# How do I filter a list (remove unwanted elements)?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have looked through the documentation but cannot seem to find the answer.  Suppose I have a list

```
a=(1:1000);
```

How would I perform a simple filter for example all numbers divisible by 7 and greater than 250?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  isDivisable = mod(a,7)==0;
  isGreater  = a>250;
  out = a(isDivisable & isGreater);
```

Comment: Needs elementwise `&` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a list. It is an array. And you can use boolean indexing (A vector of 1 and 0's) to collect the entries you are interested in.

So the following returns a boolean vector with '1'-s where numbers in `a` are multiples of 7:

```
div7 = mod(a, 7) == 0
```

And you can use that to get the elements you want from the vector `a`:

```
b = a(div7)
```

Returns a *new* vector with the elements where `div7` is equal to 1.

Of course, you can combine boolean vectors to get more complicated 'selectors'. So, like Andrey had shown

```
bigger250 = (a>250)
```

is a vector of the same length as `a`, but with '1'-s where a(i)>250. And you can use that together with div7_vec:

```
b = a(div7 & bigger250)
```

The `&` sign produces a new vector that is the element-wise "and" of both boolean vectors. So that would get you a vector that has '1'-s where both conditions are true.